# Is it possible to add show password functionality in login form of sylius? This script is not working

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, sylius

```
function myFunction() {
    var showpass = document.getElementsByClassName('lpass');
    if (showpass.type === "password") {
        showpass.type = "text";
    } else {
        showpass.type = "password";
    }
}
```

This script is not working. In `console.log('')` it is skipping to `else` condition directly.

Comment: Please add the actual HTML markup as it is rendered here

Comment: getElementsByClassName() will return a live HTMLcollection of all the elements with that class. So even if there's only one element with that class, you still need to use [0] or loop over the collection to find the correct element. Or just use .querySelector( '.lpass' ) which will only return the first element with that class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var showpass = document.getElementsByClassName('lpass');` returns an array so use the `0` index to get the first match.

```
var showpass = document.getElementsByClassName('lpass')[0];
```

You can see more about the function here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName